# escaping special characters in php prepared statement

Tags: php

Some of the text inputs in the user submitted form will contain special characters like > < , ' " % + & etc.
In a prepared statement, when the parameters are declared as strings, these special characters are removed. For example:

```
$text1 = 'There is 98% of >25 mm & "A category" of D++';
$stm->bind_param("s", $text1);
```

using `htmlspecialchars()` can solve some but not all. For example, `+` is completely removed. The above string, when inserted into table appears as

```
There is 98% of >25 mm
```

and if I replace `&` with `and` the following is inserted;

```
There is 98% of >25 mm and "A category" of D
```

What is the way around? Even `htmlentities()` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: you must be looking for [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: diEcho, This doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: where is `mysql_prepare()` in your question?